# Browser get hanged while executing a specific line in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using the `ExtJS gridview` to load the data. I've around 4000 records in which each record has 60 cells means there are 60 columns in gridview. I observed that my back end server is responding me in average 15 seconds which is acceptable case. After a successful response I am binding hide/show event in column menu of `gridview`. For that I am fetching the `HeaderContainer(headerCt)` and column items of gridview as below,

```
var menu = grid.headerCt.getMenu().down('#columnItem');
```

This line is taking around 50 seconds to a minute to get executed and due to this browser become unresponsive for the particular time. (I've checked in Google Chrome debugger).

Is there any alternative to get rid of this?

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using? Grids is where you can see the biggest performance improvement of ExtJS 6 over ExtJS 4.

Answer (score 0):

in your grid add plugin, this must help

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer', {

    })
]
```

Comment: I've tried this but didn't get any improvement. Anything should I write inside the create function?

Comment: can you provide more code? maybe to achieve your functionality we will find other way.

Comment: I can not share my code. But rather I can describe you what I need exactly. My use case is simple enough that as and when I hide/unhide any column from the column menu of ExtJS grid view, The grid store should be reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put that line in between this two functions.

```
    Ext.suspendLayouts();
    Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
```

Above functions will increase the performance if any layouts changes are there.

Comment: These line didn't make any difference. Still I am facing the problem.